# how to perform atomic read for double?

Tags: c#, atomic, interlocked

Why is there no Interlocked.Read function available for double since there are Interlocked.Exchange and Interlocked.CompareExchange methods available for double which can perform more complex functions atomically. Using such methods to read a double value atomically (instead of using Interlocked.Read) will add an overhead to a simple reading operation.

Could you suggest a simpler approach to read a double atomically where as another thread is updating this double using Interlocked.Exchange method.

Comment: if "another thread is updating this double" what value do you expect to retrieve? old value or new value?

Comment: @MitchWheat, doesn't other thread's update operation should be blocked until current thread's read operation is performed?

Comment: want to read new value.

Comment: @Tony: poster appears to be asking for something fast. On re-read I have no idea what they are asking! --> "...will add an overhead to a simple reading operation" - Yes, locking involves an overhead...

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry for confusion in the question. I meant an overhead compared to Interlocked.Read operation. I am creating a temp variable and using Interlocked.Exchange to read the double atomically and return the temp value. A simple Interlocked.Read seems much simpler than Interlocked.Exchange method. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it causing a bottleneck? If not, move on with something more important....

Comment: not the bottleneck, but I am more interested in correctness. What I wanted to know is that when a thread is updating a double value using Interlocked.Exchange, other thread cannot just read the double normally without losing atomicity. It has to store the value into a temp double using Interlocked.Exchange and use the temp value.

Answer (score 0):

`Interlocked.Read` for `long` [is implemented like this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/interlocked.cs,22e58906412927dc):

```
return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location,0,0);
```

That means that using `CompareExchange` instead of `Read` does not add an overhead, not for `long` and not for `double`.